KeyError: tensor(1) when trying to train Faster R-CNN model
I am getting the following error when trying to train my Faster R-CNN model. Can someone trace the source of the error or know what is wrong?:
The code for training:
!python train.py --data data_configs/custom_data.yaml --epochs 1 --imgsz 850 --model fasterrcnn_resnet50_fpn_v2 --name custom_training --batch 4 --device cuda

The error:
File "C:\Users\..\fastercnn-pytorch-training\train.py", line 574, in <module>
    main(args)

  File "C:\Users\..\fastercnn-pytorch-training\fastercnn-pytorch-training\train.py", line 414, in main batch_loss_rpn_list = train_one_epoch(

  File "C:\Users\..\fastercnn-pytorch-training\fastercnn-pytorch-training\torch_utils\engine.py", line 46, in train_one_epoch
    for images, targets in metric_logger.log_every(data_loader, print_freq, header):
  
File "C:\Users\..\fastercnn-pytorch-training\fastercnn-pytorch-training\torch_utils\utils.py", line 174, in log_every
    for batch in iterable:
 
 File "C:\Users\..\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 701, in __next__
    data = self._next_data()
 
 File "C:\Users\..\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 757, in _next_data
    data = self._dataset_fetcher.fetch(index)  # may raise StopIteration
 
 File "C:\Users\..\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\fetch.py", line 52, in fetch
    data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
 
 File "C:\Users\..\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\fetch.py", line 52, in <listcomp>
    data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
 
 File "C:\Users\..\fastercnn-pytorch-training\fastercnn-pytorch-training\datasets.py", line 317, in __getitem__
    sample = self.transforms(image=image_resized,
  
File "C:\Users\..\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\albumentations\core\composition.py", line 421, in __call__
    self.preprocess(data)
  
File "C:\Users\..\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\albumentations\core\composition.py", line 447, in preprocess
    p.preprocess(data)
 
 File "C:\Users\..\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\albumentations\core\utils.py", line 171, in preprocess
    data = self.add_label_fields_to_data(data)
  
File "C:\Users\..\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\albumentations\core\utils.py", line 220, in add_label_fields_to_data
    data[data_name] = self._process_label_fields(data, data_name)
  
File "C:\Users\..\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\albumentations\core\utils.py", line 229, in _process_label_fields
    encoded_labels = self._encode_label_field(data, data_name, label_field)
 
 File "C:\Users\..\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\albumentations\core\utils.py", line 249, in _encode_label_field
    encoded_labels = encoder.fit_transform(data[label_field]).reshape(-1, 1)
 
 File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\albumentations\core\utils.py", line 84, in fit_transform
    return self.transform(y)
 
 File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\albumentations\core\utils.py", line 80, in transform
    return np.array([self.classes_[label] for label in y])
  
File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\albumentations\core\utils.py", line 80, in <listcomp>
    return np.array([self.classes_[label] for label in y])

KeyError: tensor(1)


Hard to say without seeing the code but my guess is they key value in the self.classes_ dict is 1 (int) and you're trying to access it with tensor(1) (torch.tensor). You can call .item() on the tensor to get the int value
